# New installations not appearing in Data Explorer - Parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I deleted my installation class in the Parse Data Explorer, and created a new one. Now that it's empty no new installations are appearing in the class. What is causing this behaviour, and how can i fix it. Did Parse implement some kind of function to call in the iOS SDK before an installation can appear?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do the push guide from Parse again, and it seemed like they changed some thing in the SDK, which caused the problem!

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {


    PFPush.storeDeviceToken(deviceToken)

    let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    currentInstallation.channels = ["global"]
    currentInstallation["notifyEnabled"] = true
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground() //This line was not there initially!



}
```

I fixed it by inserting the line highlighted in the code.

Thanks for the all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you delete records from Installation table, the records will not appear again when you open your App. This easy fix is to delete the App from your device and re-install it for a device Installation record to appear again in your class. This is possibly because when you register an installation it gets cached locally by the Parse SDK on your device and will not be updated again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, but unfortunately it doesn't work by deleting the app, and installing it again from xcode :( Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you have push notifications work for you previously or are you just starting ? if it used to work, have you checked for any errors when you try to register for push notifications ?

Comment: I also dropped the whole _installation class and created a new one to see if it would help, but it didn't :(

Comment: Mo Nazami Yes they worked previously, suddenly after some time not working on the project (like 2 months), the installation class was broken.

Comment: Are you using the correct provisioning profile ? How about the certificate you uploaded to Parse ? If it stops working suddenly it is 99% because of one these two

Comment: I figured it out, please vote up my answer i provided :D